# ExitPolicy for IPv6 not recognized

Tags: configuration, ipv6

I run my Tor Instance in DualStack (IPv4 & IPv6).

```
Tor 0.4.7.7
```

My Exit-Policy in `torrc` looks like:

```
ExitPolicy                  accept6 *:80-81     # HTTP - Hypertext Transfer Protocol / web browsing
ExitPolicy                  accept6 *:443       # HTTPS - Hypertext Transfer Protocol over TLS/SSL / secure web browsing
ExitPolicy                  reject6 *:*
```

Why is my IPv6 ExitPolicy not considered?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set IPv6Exit to 1?

(30 chars)

Comment: Nope! I haven't set this Option. Where comes that from? I cannot find it in the manpage -> https://linux.die.net/man/1/tor

Comment: you're my man! Solved by adding the Option to `/etc/tor/torrc`